# How to override _registerJsPrice($price) function in Configurable.php Block in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, overrides, preference, override-block

I am trying to override __registerJsPrice($price) function in configurable.php

This function is work when we change swatch.

Path of configurable.php is `/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Block/Product/View/Type`

**This is Protected function.** so I overrided using preference method

**Step 1:-** create di.xml file in Folder **app/code/Webkul/Hello/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Webkul\Hello\Block\Rewrite\Product\Configurable" />
</config>
```

Step 2:-create **Configurable.php** Block file in Folder **/magento/app/code/Webkul/Hello/Block/Rewrite/Product**

```
<?php

    namespace Webkul\Hello\Block\Rewrite\Product;

    class Configurable extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable
    {
        protected function _registerJsPrice($price)
        {
            return str_replace(',', '.', $price + 11);
        }
    }
```

I Change return **str_replace(',', '.', $price);** to return **str_replace(',', '.', $price + 11);** it mean when i change swatch the price increase by +11 rupees.

I changed this in the core file and the changes were shown but when I override at that time no any charges shown.

Comment: can you try with plugin.

Comment: yes but as per Magento doc, we can't override protected function using the plugin. and this is protected function @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Comment: any help @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1:- create di.xml file in Folder app/code/Webkul/Hello/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" type="Webkul\Hello\Block\Rewrite\Product\Configurable" />
</config>
```

Step 2:-create Configurable.php Block file in Folder /magento/app/code/Webkul/Hello/Block/Rewrite/Product

```
<?php

    namespace Webkul\Hello\Block\Rewrite\Product;

    class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
    {
        protected function _registerJsPrice($price)
    {
        return str_replace(',', '.', $price + 11);
    }
    }
```